# Retrieve Node attribute value from hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have a entity class definition in hbm mapping file as below

```
<class entity-name="user" node="User" table="dbo.user">
```

Is there any way to use ClassMetadata or AbstractEntityPersister to retrieve the node attribute value "User"?

I found there is way to retrieve using `getEntityName()` and `getTableName()`, but how about node?